# Create new variables with names and values conditional on existing variables

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-wrangling

This is a data wrangling problem.

I have a data.frame

```
example.dat <- 
    data.frame(c_1 = c(2, 3, 4, 1),
               c_2 = c(4, 1, 3, 2),
               T1_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               T1_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               T1_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               T1_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               T2_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               T2_2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               T2_3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               T2_4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               T3_1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               T3_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               T3_3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               T3_4 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               T4_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               T4_2 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               T4_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               T4_4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Where the variables starting with `T` are formatted to describe `attribute_position`. For example, `T1_1` is attribute 1 in the first position. These variables are dummy coded as either present (1) or absent (0). The two variables starting with `c` describe the first and second choice. Therefore, this data.frame describes four instances of a first and second choice between 4 attributes, where each attribute appears once* per instance but it's position can change between each instance (*NOTE: attributes might not appear at all in the real problem. But if they do appear, they appear a maximum of once per instance).

In the first instance (first row), the attribute in the second position (`T2_2`) is chosen first and the attribute in the fourth position (`T4_4`) is chosen second. In the fourth instance (fourth row), the attribute in the first position (`T2_1`) is chosen first and the attribute in the second position (`T3_2`) is chosen second.

I want to add a set of 12 variables where there are only three possible positions (1:3). Whichever `attribute_position` is selected first (`c_1`), that attribute should now appear absent, and the positions of remaining attributes shuffle up. For example, according to the previous examples, respectively, the second choices (`c_2`) would be `T4_3` and `T3_1`. It is not just the chosen attributes that are affected though, the positions of all remaining present attributes should be modified accordingly. I appreciate there might be better ways to represent this, but I need to format it as follows:

```
  desired.dat <- 
    data.frame(c_1 = c(2, 3, 4, 1),
               c_2 = c(3, 1, 3, 1),
               original_T1_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               original_T1_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               original_T1_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               original_T1_4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               original_T2_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               original_T2_2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               original_T2_3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               original_T2_4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               original_T3_1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               original_T3_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               original_T3_3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               original_T3_4 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               original_T4_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               original_T4_2 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
               original_T4_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
               original_T4_4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               
               modified_T1_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               modified_T1_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               modified_T1_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
               modified_T2_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
               modified_T2_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
               modified_T2_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
               modified_T3_1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
               modified_T3_2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
               modified_T3_3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               modified_T4_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
               modified_T4_2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
               modified_T4_3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

I'm happy to provide further details if required. Thanks!